# execute a large sql file sqlite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

- i need to execute 178 mg sql file (bdd RED: Rich_Epinions_Dataset_anonym )
- i have this error message :MemoryError
- i use sqlite and python here my code :

---

```
import sqlite3

def import():
    print("Opened database ...")

    conn = sqlite3.connect('F:\\PROJECT\\testDict.db')
    print("Opened database successfully")

    qry = open('F:\\PROJECT\\epinions_anonym.sql', 'r').read()
    sqlite3.complete_statement(qry)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.executescript(qry)
    except Exception as e:
        MessageBoxW = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
        errorMessage = databaseFile + ': ' + str(e)
        MessageBoxW(None, errorMessage, 'Error', 0)
        cursor.close()
        raise

import()
```

Comment: Instead of python, use the sqlite shell program: `sqlite3 your.db < yourdata.sql`

Comment: Your `.complete_statement(qry)` are useless. Read [sqlite3.complete_statement(sql)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.complete_statement)

Comment: @Shawn thanks..it works

Comment: for a large file it.s better to use mysqlworkbench .. it.s what i did now